# ifort mpi-openmp segmentation fault

Tags: linux, fortran, mpi, openmp, mpich

I have a hybrid mpi-openmp code that crashes with a segmentation fault, bad termination error.  I compile using mpif90/ifort, and use mpich2.  Here is the compile line that I use and get errors:

```
mpif90.mpich2 -f90=ifort -DAMD64_LNX -openmp -o jack_openmp.exe laplace.f
```

When using this command, if I run from one node, pointing to a machines file that includes a different node I get the segmentation fault:

```
=====================================================================================
=   BAD TERMINATION OF ONE OF YOUR APPLICATION PROCESSES
=   EXIT CODE: 11
=   CLEANING UP REMAINING PROCESSES
=   YOU CAN IGNORE THE BELOW CLEANUP MESSAGES
=====================================================================================
APPLICATION TERMINATED WITH THE EXIT STRING: Segmentation fault (signal 11)
```

However, if I run this from a specific node (say node1) and only have "node1" in the machines file it then runs as expected, using the right amount of threads per node (say if "node1" was listed twice in the machines file and the mpiexec command was like "mpiexec -np 2 ...").

A second thing I tried is instead of linking "-openmp", I link in "-liomp5".  When I do this, the code compiles and runs, even across nodes.  However it does not run in any threaded sense.  The "omp_get_num_threads" will return 8 threads per node (which is correct), but it will only run one thread per node listed in the machines file, thus not doing any actual threading.

I am using the latest ifort compiler (12.1.2) and mpich2 as noted.  The stack size is unlimited, verified through "ulimit -a" and seeing it as unlimited.

The source code for the laplace.f file follows:

```
      program lpmlp
      include 'mpif.h'
      include "omp_lib.h" 

      integer imax,jmax,im1,im2,jm1,jm2,it,itmax
      parameter (imax=10001,jmax=10001)
      parameter (im1=imax-1,im2=imax-2,jm1=jmax-1,jm2=jmax-2)
      parameter (itmax=100)
      real*8 u(imax,jmax),du(imax,jmax),umax,dumax,tol,pi
      parameter (umax=10.0,tol=1.0e-6,pi=3.14159)
! Additional MPI parameters
      integer istart,iend,jstart,jend
      integer size,rank,ierr,istat(MPI_STATUS_SIZE),mpigrid,length
      integer grdrnk,dims(1),gloc(1),up,down,isize,jsize
      integer ureq,dreq
      integer ustat(MPI_STATUS_SIZE),dstat(MPI_STATUS_SIZE)
      real*8 tstart,tend,gdumax
      logical cyclic(1)
      real*8 uibuf(imax),uobuf(imax),dibuf(imax),dobuf(imax)
! OpenMP parameters
      integer nthrds,nthreads      

! Initialize
      call MPI_INIT_THREAD(MPI_THREAD_FUNNELED,IMPI_prov,ierr)
      call MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD,rank,ierr)
      call MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD,size,ierr)
! 1D linear topology
      dims(1)=size
      cyclic(1)=.FALSE.
      call MPI_CART_CREATE(MPI_COMM_WORLD,1,dims,cyclic,.true.,mpigrid
     +     ,ierr)
      call MPI_COMM_RANK(mpigrid,grdrnk,ierr)
      call MPI_CART_COORDS(mpigrid,grdrnk,1,gloc,ierr)
      call MPI_CART_SHIFT(mpigrid,0,1,down,up,ierr)
      istart=2
      iend=imax-1
      jsize=jmax/size
      jstart=gloc(1)*jsize+1
      if (jstart.LE.1) jstart=2
      jend=(gloc(1)+1)*jsize
      if (jend.GE.jmax) jend=jmax-1
      nthrds=OMP_GET_NUM_PROCS()
      print*,"Rank=",rank,"Threads=",nthrds
      call omp_set_num_threads(nthrds)

!$OMP PARALLEL DEFAULT(SHARED) PRIVATE(i,j)
! Initialize -- done in parallel to force "first-touch" distribution
! on ccNUMA machines (i.e. O2k)
!$OMP DO
      do j=jstart-1,jend+1
         do i=istart-1,iend+1
            u(i,j)=0.0
            du(i,j)=0.0
         enddo
         u(imax,j)=umax*sin(pi*float(j-1)/float(jmax-1))
      enddo
!$OMP END DO
!$OMP END PARALLEL

! Main computation loop
      call MPI_BARRIER(MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
      tstart=MPI_WTIME()
      do it=1,itmax
! We have to keep the OpenMP and MPI calls segregated...
        call omp_set_num_threads(nthrds)

!$OMP PARALLEL DEFAULT(SHARED) PRIVATE(i,j)
!$OMP MASTER
        dumax=0.0
!$OMP END MASTER
!$OMP DO REDUCTION(max:dumax)
         do j=jstart,jend
            do i=istart,iend
               !nthreads = OMP_GET_NUM_THREADS()
               !print*,"Jack",rank,nthreads,nthrds
               du(i,j)=0.25*(u(i-1,j)+u(i+1,j)+u(i,j-1)+u(i,j+1))-u(i,j)
               dumax=max(dumax,abs(du(i,j)))
            enddo
         enddo
!$OMP END DO
!$OMP DO
         do j=jstart,jend
            do i=istart,iend
               u(i,j)=u(i,j)+du(i,j)
            enddo
         enddo
!$OMP END DO
!$OMP END PARALLEL
! Compute the overall residual
         call MPI_REDUCE(dumax,gdumax,1,MPI_REAL8,MPI_MAX,0
     +        ,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)

! Send phase
         if (down.NE.MPI_PROC_NULL) then
            j=1
            do i=istart,iend
               dobuf(j)=u(i,jstart)
               j=j+1
            enddo
            length=j-1
            call MPI_ISEND(dobuf,length,MPI_REAL8,down,it,mpigrid,
     +           dreq,ierr)
         endif
         if (up.NE.MPI_PROC_NULL) then
            j=1
            do i=istart,iend
               uobuf(j)=u(i,jend)
               j=j+1
            enddo
            length=j-1
            call MPI_ISEND(uobuf,length,MPI_REAL8,up,it,mpigrid,
     +           ureq,ierr)
         endif
! Receive phase
         if (down.NE.MPI_PROC_NULL) then
            length=iend-istart+1
            call MPI_RECV(dibuf,length,MPI_REAL8,down,it,
     +           mpigrid,istat,ierr)
            call MPI_WAIT(dreq,dstat,ierr)
            j=1
            do i=istart,iend
               u(i,jstart-1)=dibuf(j)
               j=j+1
            enddo
         endif
         if (up.NE.MPI_PROC_NULL) then
            length=iend-istart+1
            call MPI_RECV(uibuf,length,MPI_REAL8,up,it,
     +           mpigrid,istat,ierr)
            call MPI_WAIT(ureq,ustat,ierr)
            j=1
            do i=istart,iend
               u(i,jend+1)=uibuf(j)
               j=j+1
            enddo
         endif
         write (rank+10,*) rank,it,dumax,gdumax
         if (rank.eq.0) write (1,*) it,gdumax
      enddo
      call MPI_BARRIER(MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
      tend=MPI_WTIME()
      if (rank.EQ.0) then
         write(*,*) 'Calculation took ',tend-tstart,'s. on ',size,
     +        ' MPI processes'
     +        ,' with ',nthrds,' OpenMP threads per process'
      endif
      call MPI_FINALIZE(ierr)
      stop
      end
```

When running the -liomp5 linked in compiling it is seen that:

```
call omp_set_num_threads(nthrds)
```

is executed with nthrds = 8, verified through print statements, however when immediately checking it via:

```
nthreads = OMP_GET_NUM_THREADS()
```

the resultant nthreads = 1.  However, in the case that completes when linking in -openmp at compilation (all the same node in the machines file, with the run started from the same node), nthreads = 8.

If I specify the headnode name first in the machines file longer, saying:

```
=====================================================================================
=   BAD TERMINATION OF ONE OF YOUR APPLICATION PROCESSES
=   EXIT CODE: 11
=   CLEANING UP REMAINING PROCESSES
=   YOU CAN IGNORE THE BELOW CLEANUP MESSAGES
=====================================================================================
[proxy:0:1@c403] HYD_pmcd_pmip_control_cmd_cb (./pm/pmiserv/pmip_cb.c:906): assert (!closed) failed
[proxy:0:1@c403] HYDT_dmxu_poll_wait_for_event (./tools/demux/demux_poll.c:77): callback returned error status
[proxy:0:1@c403] main (./pm/pmiserv/pmip.c:226): demux engine error waiting for event
[mpiexec@c403] HYDT_bscu_wait_for_completion (./tools/bootstrap/utils/bscu_wait.c:70): one of the processes terminated badly; aborting
[mpiexec@c403] HYDT_bsci_wait_for_completion (./tools/bootstrap/src/bsci_wait.c:23): launcher returned error waiting for completion
[mpiexec@c403] HYD_pmci_wait_for_completion (./pm/pmiserv/pmiserv_pmci.c:189): launcher returned error waiting for completion
[mpiexec@c403] main (./ui/mpich/mpiexec.c:397): process manager error waiting for completion
```

A lot of info, but hopefully not too much.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: my recommendations: (1) mixing MPI and OpenMP, I would start practicing with a simple code sample (http://www.slac.stanford.edu/comp/unix/farm/mpi_and_openmp.html).  (2) Did you try a debugger to find out where exactly in your code the segfault occurs?

Comment: @KyleKanos I retagged due to [this request on meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/226446/158100). If you are unhappy with that please share your ideas there.

Answer (score 2):

It might be OpenMP thread stack size is too small. Have you tried setting `OMP_STACKSIZE` with a large size?

```
% export OMP_STACKSIZE=512m # may be another value: 32m, 64m, 128m, 256m ...
```

Each OpenMP thread uses private stack memory, the default stack size is 2MB in IA-32 and 4MB in Intel64 architecture.

Answer (score 0):

Try running your program under [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) (make sure to recompile with `-g` for debuggging symbols first).  Something like this will probably be helpful:

```
% mpiexec -n 2 valgrind -q ./jack_openmp.exe
```

If it reports any warnings/errors in your program (and not just some random system library), then there are almost certainly bugs in your code that you need to fix.  Take a look at the indicated stack trace and figure out why Valgrind is complaining.

Comment: An update of findings.  After much troubleshooting I discovered there is a sensitivity to the size of the declared static arrays.  If the static arrays are small the code runs fine, if they are "too big" the code crashes with the odd segmentation faults listed above.  In the case of the example fortran program, the magic number is 720.  That is if imax = jmax = 720 then the code runs to completion correctly.  If imax = jmax >= 721 the code crashes with the seg faults.

Comment: As a hunch I retooled the static arrays to be the same size but be dynamically allocated and things work perfectly no matter how big the array is.  I don't have a good understanding of the difference between how statically and dynamically allocated arrays are handled but this seems key in the problem.  This doesn't solve my problem though (simply retooling to dynamic allocation), as this code is just a test case for a much bigger code.  I still need to figure out what compiler and/or Ubuntu settings need to change to make things work.